# How to prevent Laravel from sending SQL query parameters to the error handler?

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, bugsnag

Our Laravel application uses Bugsnag for error reporting, but I'm not allowed to send any user-identifiable data to this service. Today, the following error popped up in Bugsnag:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException · SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
> constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
> 'x' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert
> into `notifications` (`id`, `type`, `data`, `read_at`,
> `notifiable_id`, `notifiable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
> (a, b, {"id":c,"title":"d","uri":"e","message":"f","action":"g"}, ...))

This bit ...

```
{"id":c,"title":"d","uri":"e","message":"f","action":"g"}
```

... contains user-identifiable data. How do I prevent Laravel from sending this to Bugsnag (or to any error handler, for that matter)?

Comment: Hi - please could you write into support@bugsnag.com with a link to the error in question and we can help you from there. Thanks!

Comment: see [zend.exception-ignore-args](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72363195/285587)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this part of Bugsnag's documentation:

https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/php/laravel/customizing-error-reports/

...where you can implement a callback function to check for this sort of data in most parts of the error (class, message, stack, etc) - and set it to another value to redact before the error is sent to Bugsnag's servers. You can also return false to prevent specific error reports from being sent at all.

You'll have access to get/set different data depending on the platform, which will be apparent in the documentation.