# php mysqli_connect error exposes information in error_log file, how to prevent that?

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

In the main directory of the website in the `index.php` file, On the line 11 I have this line:

```
require_once('../db.php');
```

The `db.php` file contains the information for connecting to MySQL server and database which is under the root directory one level above the `public_html` directory.

I have disabled php error report so that the user won't see the errors and by doing that it stores the errors in a file called `error_log`.

Sometimes I see this error in that file for an unknown reason:

```
[24-May-2022 00:18:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No such file or directory in /home/username123/db.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 /home/username123/db.php(17): mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username123_dbname...', 'password', 'db_username', 1234)
#1 /home/username123/public_html/index.php(11): require_once('/home/username123/...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/username123/db.php on line 17
```

And the line 17 in the `db.php` is this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, 1234) or die ("error");
```

I don't know why this happens. That `db.php` file is always there and visiting the home page doesn't have any problems.

But my question is this:

**In the error log it shows the username and password and database name etc, How can I prevent that?**

Comment: IMO it shouldn't really matter...who is able to see the error log file who isn't also able to see the source code (and therefore obtain the same information)?

Comment: @ADyson yes, but what if I hadn't disabled the php error report to the user, would it print this information to the browser for the user?

Comment: In PHP 8.2, [support is being added for redacting sensitive information from backtrackes](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/redact_parameters_in_back_traces), which may or may not help you in the future.

Comment: If you forget to disable PHP display_errors then your code will have a lot more issues than just mysqli_connect

Comment: @ChrisHaas So I should just wait for PHP 8.2 release then

Comment: @MDP, I’m not saying that, I’m just pointing out that this is something that the PHP community is aware of and addressing. If you read through it, and then especially read the [discussion thread](https://externals.io/message/116853), you’ll find the current hacky ways that people use such as `set_error_handler` which will work today.

Comment: Otherwise, for that very specific function call, it might be best to wrap it in an error handler of your own. The file not found is an issue with sockets (as far as I understand it). You might also want to try `127.0.0.1` literally, which is what I have to do on one of my WSL machines.

Comment: `but what if I hadn't disabled the php error report to the user, would it print this information to the browser`...yes it would, but you didn't do that so you're ok.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because it's default behavior for exceptions in PHP. An uncaught exception gets converted to string when logged, and such a conversion includes adding a stack trace to the error message. And by default a stack trace would contain a list of arguments supplied for each function.

Yes, seeing your password openly in the logs can be uncomfortable. There are different options to deal with this.

**1. Exclude sensitive information from the stack trace**

Starting from PHP 8.2 it will be possible to [exclude certain information from the stack trace](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/redact_parameters_in_back_traces). The most preferred method.

**2. Exclude arguments from the stack trace**

You can use [zend.exception-ignore-args](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.exception-ignore-args) PHP configuration directive to temporarily disablie adding function arguments to the  stack trace. You can do it like this

```
$ignore_args = ini_get('zend.exception_ignore_args');
ini_set('zend.exception_ignore_args', 1);
$con = mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, 1234);
ini_set('zend.exception_ignore_args', $ignore_args);
```

And your credentials will disappear from from the stack trace. Thus your error message will look like

```
[24-May-2022 00:18:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No such file or directory in /home/username123/db.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 /home/username123/db.php(17): mysqli_connect()
#1 /home/username123/public_html/index.php(11): require_once('/home/username123/...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/username123/db.php on line 17
```

This is not very useful option, as the very parameters we threw off could be the actual clue we are looking for to pinpoint the problem.

**3. Leave everything as is**

To be honest, whatever sensitive information can appear in any error message and any stack trace. You won't be able to redact every single sensitive parameter. Better concentrate on guarding your logs because error messages can be indispensable source of information even without passwords.